# Globbing and regular expression prob with bash script

Tags: perl, bash, grep, glob

I have a problem with my regex:

My script is written in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Inverse les colonnes 1 et 2
while(<>){
    my @cols  = split (/\|/);
    print "$cols[-3]/$cols[-4]\n";
}

exit;
```

I create an alias using the command :

```
alias inverseur="perl /laboratoire10/inverseur_colonnes.pl
```

I am hoping to accomplish the following:

Write a "bash" script that creates a file container for each movie title (.avi) in the file.

The original file is: http://www.genxvideo.com/genxinventory-current.xls
but I have since renamed it to liste_films.csv .

All quotation marks, spaces, dashes, and other strange characters must be replaced by an underscore, "_".

The group would become the directory name and the title of the movie will follow the file name suffix( .avi). In order to do this, the code must process the fields "title" and "class" in reverse. You can reverse the fields "title" and "class" with the alias "inverter" created earlier.

The script will obviously create each directory in "/laboratoire10" before creating the .avi files. There should be 253 valid directories total. Directories are being created through a "|" with the command "xargs mkdir-pv /."

I need help augmenting my current code with a command to find .avi files whose name contains the string min/maj "wood

Comment: You really need to work on translating this into English. I'm French and I don't understand the second half of your post. It would help if you asked about the part that gives you trouble instead of dumping your whole homework assignment.

Comment: Sorry i'm French and not very good in english. Is not all my homework assignement just a part.

Comment: It's not clear what you need help with. It sounds like you want us to write the code for you, but this isn't not a code-writing service. If that's not your intention, specify what problems you are encountering.

Comment: Mentionnes quels problèmes spécifiques que tu as rencontrer. En ce moment, tu nous a simplement demandé d'écrire ton program pour toi.

Comment: Hum forget it i have too much difficulty too exprimate my point in english. Thanks obsiously :) i will search a ICQ french UNIX too help me :P haha!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do.  Under the assumption you have a | separated CSV and wish to have a directory tree with CATEGORY/TITLE and the file named "cans.avi" under each directory with that name, here is a one liner perl script.

```
perl -mText::CSV -e '$csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char=>"|",binary=>1,auto_diag => 1 } ) || die; open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0] or die; while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) { $file = cleaner($row->[1])."/".cleaner($row->[0]); print "mkdir $file; touch $file/cans.avi\n"; } sub cleaner($) { my($f) = @_; $f =~ s/\W/_/g; $f;}'  ~/tmp/genxinventory-current.csv
```

I converted the XLS file to | separated CSV using libreoffice, so your conversion mileage (kilometerage?) may vary.

Comment: "One Liner" is a bit much, when the horizontal scrollbar on the code fragment shows less than a quarter of your original input. :) -- but excellent crystal ball work. :)